# Showing that $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\tfrac12x+o(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, education

I have found that a nice way to explain to students what the derivative is the number $A$ such that
$$f(x+dx)=f(x) + A\,dx+o(dx),$$
motivated by the idea of approximating $f$ around $x$.

If we take this as *the* starting point of what differentiation is, it's easy to obtain things like $(2+dx)^2 \approx 4 + 4\,dx$ for small $x$, and so on for more general polynomials. But it would be nice to give a more non-trivial example. It feels like the next natural step is something like
$$\sqrt{1+dx} = 1 + \tfrac12dx+o(dx),$$
but how can I show this without using "heavy machinery"? At this point I've only started the topic, and my students have only seen $\epsilon$-$\delta$ style proofs of some basic limits (plus I mentioned some of the standard ones like $\sin x/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$).

This is essentially an easy case of the more general power rule for derivatives: $d(x^r)=rx^{r-1}\,dx$, but all proofs I've seen use logarithms or the inverse function theorem (changing $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ to $f^{-1}(y)=y^2$ etc.). Is there a more direct way I can show that
$$\lim_{dx\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+dx}-(1+\tfrac12\,dx)}{dx}=0?$$
Or maybe $\sqrt{1+x}$ is not the most natural "next step" up from polynomials, and there is another easier example I can give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may say that
$$
\sqrt {1 + dx}  - \left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}dx} \right) = \frac{{1 + dx - \left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}dx} \right)^2 }}{{\sqrt {1 + dx}  + \left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}dx} \right)}} = \frac{{ - \frac{1}{4}(dx)^2 }}{{\sqrt {1 + dx}  + \left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}dx} \right)}} = o(dx)
$$
as $dx \to 0$.

Comment: Very nice, I forgot about this technique of "rationalising the numerator".

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to obtain the derivative "from scratch" as follows: we look for the value of $\alpha$ that minimizes the error

$$\sqrt{x+1}-1-\alpha x$$ for small $x$.

We can rework the expression as follows:

$$\sqrt{x+1}-1-\alpha x=\frac{x+1-(1+\alpha x)^2}{\sqrt{x+1}+1+\alpha x}=\frac{x-2\alpha x+\alpha^2x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}+1+\alpha x}\sim x\frac{1-2\alpha+\alpha^2x}{2}.$$ The denominator $2$ is justified by the fact that for smaller and smaller $x$, $x$ becomes negligible. In the numerator, $\alpha^2x$ could also be considered negligible, unless the constant term vanishes. Indeed, with $\alpha=\dfrac12$, the error is virtually

$$\frac{x^2}8=o(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Do they know Newton's approximations, which are a consequence of the binomial series? If yes, you can easily show using that series. Since $dx$ is small, you neglect the higher powers, and the desired expression is obtained. The limit you wish to evaluate can also be evaluated using said method.

Comment: Surely that would be a bit circular, after all the way I'm motivating differentiation is as an approximation.

Comment: No, because Newton's expansion is based upon the concept of the generalized binomial theorem, not on calculus

Answer (score -2):

Using a derivative :
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1-\frac{h}{2}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=f'(0)=0$$
where $f(h):=\sqrt{1+h}-\frac{h}{2}$.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you realise that this is not a good answer in this particular situation.

Comment: @Gary It may depend: you can start a lecture on derivative and show basic formulas like the derivative of $x\mapsto x^n$ or $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ (which is straightforward actually), and then the above answer provides you with a direct proof of the Taylor expansion at 0. That's why I've started by writing "Using a derivative".

Comment: @Nicolas What is a derivative? This lecture starts by _defining_ the derivative of $f$ as the number $A$ for which $f(x+h) = f(x) + Ah + o(h)$. Basically I'm asking to show that $f(x)=\sqrt x$ needs $A=\frac 1{2\sqrt x}$ after having given this definition.

Comment: @LukeCollins In this order, indeed the answer I provided is useless. However, as you use some facts like $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\to0$ as $x\to0$, you could have used the limit, say, $\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x}\to\frac{1}{2}$ as $x\to0$ using the rationalising trick on this simpler case. All in all, it depends on how exactly you want to proceed, and this answer is only useful when you have the derivative (shown by hand), whence my first sentence. Now, seeing your comment, I perfectly understand that this is not the way you want to follow.